Azure Function Project Template Issue
When creating an Azure Function App in .Net 8 Isolated in VS2022 why does the project template always create a Function with IActionResult instead of HttpResponseData?
I have tried mostly everything but cannot get this to work.
Any idea how I could fix this?
Thanks
Tried VS2022 VS Code but both create IActionResult instead of HttpResponseData not sure why

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As mentioned in the official MSDOC, IActionResult is being added for Asp.Net Core Integration in Azure functions.
If you select .NET 8.0 Isolated as template during creation of Azure function, the function uses IActionResult by default.
I have created an Isolated Azure functions with .NET 8.0 Isolated:
[Function("Function1")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
}

.csproj:
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


To work with HttpResponseData in .NET 8.0 Isolated Azure functions, remove the AspNet core related dependencies and modify the default code as given below:
[Function("Function1")]
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

    return response;
}

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj:
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

Output:


I thought we were supposed to use HttpResponseData instead of IActionResult in the  .Net 8 Isolated process mode - Which is better and which one should be used? Thx

I would suggest to use IActionResult for better performance.

@SaroshWadia, Is the issue resolved?

If I follow the above I can switch from IActionResult to HttpResponseData and it works but my question is why does the new VS2022 Project template not do that by itself

As mentioned in the provided MsDoc, .NET 8.0 isolated uses the new template IActionResult.
